# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el circulo se quede estático mientras muevo la imagen en flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

tengo el siguiente problema tengo una imagen que le puse InteractiveViewer hace el movimiento de la imagen bien pero cuando le quiero poner un circulo o un icono encima, cuando muevo la imagen se mueve con todo el icono o circulo necesitaria que se mantenga fijo cuando muevo la imagen mando codigo.

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pruebamapa/main.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyAppprueba());

class MyAppprueba extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Material App Bar'),
          ),
          body: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              InteractiveViewer(
                child: Image.asset('assets/Map1.jpg'),
                minScale: 0.1,
                maxScale: 1.6,
                constrained: false,
              ),
Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                decoration:
                    BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.purple ),
              ),
```

Comment: No todos podemos ver las imágenes :) Pon el código _como texto, con formato_.

Answer (score 0):

lo que entiendo por tu pregunta es que estás envolviendo en un `InteractiveViewer` únicamente la imagen, entonces lo que podrías hacer para que solamente se mueva la imagen, es agregar en ese mismo `stack` tu icono o circulo y arrastar la imagen debajo del icono o arrastrarla donde tú quieras, cabe recalcar que en el Stack tú puedes mover tu widget sin problema, hice un ejemplo con tu mismo código:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Material App Bar'),
  ),
  body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.purple),
      ),
       //reemplace la imagen por un container para poder hacer el 
       //ejemplo, tu coloca la imagen
      InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: const EdgeInsets.all(double.infinity),
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black),
        ),
        minScale: 0.4,
        maxScale: 4,
        constrained: false,
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: const Color.fromRGBO(255, 8, 0, 160))),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```